# How can I add a value (setText) to a Material Design TextInputLayout?

Tags: java, android, settext

How do I setText to a Material Design TextInputLayout (Material Design) in Android Studio?

```
 //setValue
   BarCode.setText(MainPage.ResultCode.getText());
```

```
    TextInputLayout BarCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_discharge_product);

        BarCode = findViewById(R.id.barcodeAdd);
        BarCode.setText(MainPage.ResultCode.getText()
```

The above code did not work for me.

My XML code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/barcodeAdd"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="Bar Code"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You should set text to the `TextInputEditText` or `EditText`

Comment: @Nongthonbam Tonthoi, can you please a  snippet please

Comment: What is `BarCode` ? I guess it is the `TextInputLayout`, so instead of it use the `TextInputEditText`. Post the relevant part of the code.

Comment: @ Nongthonbam Tonthoi, i have edited the code above.

Comment: What is `barcodeAdd` ? You can see it in the xml file

Comment: ```barcodeAdd``` is the id of the TextInputLayout input. i have uploaded the xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213093/discussion-between-nongthonbam-tonthoi-and-anesu-phiri).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the syntax... use it as appropriate in your code:

```
mTextInputLayout.getEditText().setText("your text");
```

and

```
mTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
binding.istwert.editText?.text = binding.inhalt.editText?.text
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, get a reference to the TextInputEditText inside the TextInputLayout.
Then, set the text on the TextInputEditText.

// Declare both TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText
TextInputLayout BarCodeLayout;
TextInputEditText BarCode;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discharge_product);

    // Initialize both TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText
    BarCodeLayout = findViewById(R.id.barcodeAdd);
    BarCode = (TextInputEditText) BarCodeLayout.getEditText();

    // Now, set the text on the TextInputEditText
    if (BarCode != null) {
        BarCode.setText(MainPage.ResultCode.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
TextInputEditText inpedit_txt;

inpedit_txt = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.id_of_input_edit_text);
inpedit_txt.setText(String.valueOf("Your text"))
```

Comment: answer readability can be improved a lot by formatting, eg. sharing code fragments in code blocks. Here you can find details on how to do that and more: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help